# REST webclient APPLICATION_XML to java object

Tags: java, jaxb

> I have created a client code, for calling one REST services,its giving
>   me response in APPLICATION_XML, I need to create java objects from it,
>   so that they are easily accessible through getter and setters, I have
>   the JAXB classes, but I am unable to get response through it, as its
>   missing XML root element, and I dont have permission to edit it, what
>   is my best way here ??

```
 private void run() throws JAXBException {

            //needs to change based on input
            String baseurl = "URL To Invoke REST Client";

            String uname ="uname";
            String passwrd = "password";
            String authentication = uname+":"+passwrd;
            WebClient client = WebClient.create(baseurl);
            String authorisationHeader = "Basic "+ org.apache.cxf.common.util.Base64Utility.encode(authentication.getBytes());

            client.header("Authorization", authorisationHeader);
            WebClient getClient = client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
            System.out.println(client.get(String.class));

            //GroupProductAttributesResponse productDetails = client.get(GroupProductAttributesResponse.class) ;
            //System.out.println(productDetails);


        }
```

Comment: Did you try something like this client.get(JaxBElement.class)?

Comment: Yes , its giving error like  unexpected element (uri:"", local:"groupProductAttributesResponse"). Expected elements are (none)]

Comment: Can Anyone help with an answer ? I am kind of stuck.